# How do I import objects based off of an excel sheet with its fields?

Tags: map, import

I have an excel sheet with columns for various field names for a custom object. I know there is some way to map these values to fields in an object and import them, because I've heard it mentioned before, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader), or you can use the Data Import Wizard.

The Data Loader is a seperate application you can download from:

> Setup > Administer > Data Management > Data Loader

Or, you can access the browser based Data Import Wizard from:

> Setup > Administer > Data Management > Data Import Wizard

Both do the same thing although I personally prefer using the Data Loader of the Data Import Wizard, but essentially both processes are the same:

- Log in (either to Salesforce via your Browser for the Data Import Wizard or via the Data Loader (don't forget to append your security token to your password if you use the Data Loader))
- Select a Spreadsheet
- Select an Object
- Map the columns to fields
- Go!

Salesforce will then effectively batch execute DML on records, by default doing 200 at a time.

Comment: Thanks -- this is what I thought I should do, but downloading it is not an option (I don't have admin privileges on this computer to do so) and when I try the in-browser option, it just loads a blank screen. The salesforce page is still there with headers and the side bar, all of that, but the main space where you'd expect to see things is just white. Could this just be a browser thing, or might I need some special privileges to use it? I have admin permissions...

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Honestly, I'd talk to whoever is responsible for installing things and get them to install the Data Loader. As for the content not loading, that could be a browser problem. In which case I'd try a few different browsers. If it were permissions, I'd expect you to get a good ole' insufficient priviledges error, ergo I imagine it could be your browser. Maybe it just needs updating if you can't install anything?

Comment: I figured it didn't have to do with permissions, but thought couldn't hurt to ask. Tried a different browser, same thing. I'll just wait for the data loader. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dan's second suggestion "Setup > Administer > Data Management > Data Import Wizard" is in-browser, doesn't require you to install anything on your desktop.